# Why are odoo openerp changes to python files and view files not visible?

Tags: python, odoo

I am new to odoo. I am running it in docker container with mounted source code. Why I change some xml file or python file changes are not visible.
I tried restarting server but nothing. I also try changing fils directly in docker container but changes are not visible at all.

Any idea why odoo is not showing changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Odoo with the `-u` options for the changes to be applied:

```
./odoo.py -u changed_module_name
```

Comment: I am running odoo with python /opt/odoo/openerp-server -c /etc/odoo/odoo-server.conf (from supervisor)

Comment: Than add the `-u changed_module_name` option to this command.